# Storing Android user settings

Tags: android

So far, I have the opportunity to choose in the settings which user prefers the theme: system, dark or light. And which navbar is more convenient: compact or full. I can't find anywhere what is the best way to store the user's selection and restore it when logging into the application. In the future, the settings will expand and store everything in sharedpreferences, I think it's not a good idea. Maybe storage in a local database Room or make some kind of DataStore? Can you tell me how to do this correctly and maybe there is a solution to the problem somewhere on github or in the article?

I was thinking of making something like this data class:

```
data class UserData(
    val darkThemeConfig: DarkThemeConfig,
    val navigationConfig: NavigationViewConfig
)
```

And somehow transfer data via Flow. But how do you save and restore them when you open the application? Please share articles and githabs with a similar implementation.

Comment: "In the future, the settings will expand and store everything in sharedpreferences, I think it's not a good idea." -- Why is that?

Comment: @dominicoder I need to create a bunch of parameters for each setting?